# Cannot parse local date time in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, datetime-format

In my Spring Boot application, I need to handle a form with date time field and convert it to `LocalDateTime` in Java.

I specified pattern `"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"` and it fails to convert when I submit the form with input value `1990-01-01 10:10`.

Here is the form object:

```
public class UserForm {
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("")
    public String userForm(UserForm userForm) {
        return "/users/form";
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public String postForm(@Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        System.out.println(userForm + " " + bindingResult);
        return "/users/form";
    }
}
```

And Thymeleaf form:

```
<form th:object="${userForm}" th:action="@{/users}" method="post">
    <span th:each="err: ${#fields.errors('dateTime')}" th:text="${err}" style="background-color:red;color:white;"/>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{dateTime}"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

What is wrong with this example ? How should I fix it to make it properly parse `String` to `LocalDateTime` ?

I also submitted [example application here](https://github.com/alexbezhan/localdatetime-binding-error).

**Update:**

- Under "fails to convert" I mean I'm getting exception:

  org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value 1990-01-01 10:10
- Using lowercase `yyyy` fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Define "fails to convert". And use the correct pattern. YYYY is the week year. You want the year. yyyy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Calendar year, not week-based year

Formatting pattern should be `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm`.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "1990-01-01 10:10" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm" )
)
```

The uppercase `YYYY` means the year of a week-based year rather than a calendar-year.

Study the class documentation more carefully for formatting pattern codes. Notice how they are case-sensitive.

## ISO 8601

Tip: Instead of using a custom format, stick with using standard ISO 8601 formats.

The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default. So no need to bother with specifying a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "1990-01-01T10:10"
)
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).